# tikz - Multi-line text size

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, fontsize

I am using this command:

```
\newcommand{\orgnode}[2]{\node[shape=rectangle,draw=black,align=center] at (#2) {\Large #1};}
```

to make basic ORG chart nodes. I want the text size Large. This works with one line of text, but does not work with two:

Code:

```
\orgnode{Line 1\\Line 2}{0,0}
```

Output:

[image: latex]

How can I allow the font size to be changed for all text given as the first argument, not just the first line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add it to the node options, so that it affects the whole node, and not just a part of it:

```
font=\Large
```

Also, the shape is a rectangle by default, and `draw` uses black by default. So in the end you can just write:

```
\newcommand{\orgnode}[2]{\node[draw, font=\Large, align=center] at (#2) {#1};}
```